# Show elements updated in real-time with Spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

God afternoon.
I am developing an app which show the places avalaible. In the case of Backend, researched about the SSE (Server-Sent-Event) and TailableCursors with MongoDB. I have done in Spring:

```
@Repository
public interface Repositorio extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Prueba,    String> {
  @Tailable
  Flux<Prueba> findWithTailableCursorBy();
}
```

And the controller:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping
public class Controlador {
    @Autowired
    Repositorio repo;

    @GetMapping(value = "/prueba", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<Prueba> getTodos() {
        return repo.findWithTailableCursorBy();
    }

    @GetMapping("/prueba2")
    public Flux<Prueba> prueba() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/prueba")
    public Mono<Prueba> insert(@RequestBody Prueba prueba) {
        return repo.save(prueba);
    }
}
```

The items don't change when updated. I thought that with Tailable Cursors I would solve it. However, I see that no...

Is there any way to show the rafters in real time with Spring? So I'm using EventSource on the client-side.

PS: The class model (a capped collection) is:

```
@Document(collection = "pruebas")

// Lombok's annotations
@Data @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode @ToString
public class Prueba {
    @Id private String id;

    private String nombre;
    private boolean activo = false;
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking here that ["tailable cursors"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/tailable-cursors/) are not really what you want here. These are actually special things which require ["capped collections"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/) in order to work. Modern API and server versions support ["change streams"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) which is probably more like what you are looking for. Note that neither of these "mirrors a collection" if that is what you were expecting.

Comment: See also [Spring Data MongoDB - Change Streams Example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/mongodb/change-streams) from the spring-mongo repostiory for a typical reactive example.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about this alternative. Thank you.